# detect and remove all executable files in uploaded ZIP file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on a web application using Rails which user can upload a zip file which contains its data/file/docs and etc. But I'm concerned with security right now, I want to scan the uploaded zip file and remove all kind of executable such `exe, bash and etc` how can I do this?

---

Edit: I am aware of `clamav` API for rails but it would only scan the file for malicious files not removing the executable, just imagine opening a wrong uploaded executable file in the server and the cost of this action server/business-wide!

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be better and more robust to whitelist allowed file types, and not blacklist disallowed ones (eg. executables). So you should have a list of types you allow if that is possible in your application.

Then the question is how you determine the type of a file.

The trivial way is checking the file extension, but that's not very strong. It may still be good for a first check to avoid spending precious cpu time on further checks.

After that, you can use the filemagic database to quite reliably find the type of uploaded files. You have two options:

- If your application runs on linux, you can call the `file` tool directly, something like `` filetype = `file -Ib #{filename}` `` to get the filetype. Note that `filename` in this example needs to be sanitized to avoid OS command injection!
- If you want to support Windows too (or just want to avoid calling shell commands and have nicer code), you can use the `ruby-filemagic` gem:

```rb
require 'filemagic'
filename = 'yourfile.ext'
magic = FileMagic.new
filetype = magic.file(filename)
```

The problem with `ruby-filemagic` is that it's not maintained anymore, but it would probably still work fine to find executables.